# Oracle ORA_HASH function. Will the results be constant?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, hash

We have the requirement to give a unique (per table) NUMERIC Id to multiple tables in our ERP System, because an interface to a 3rd party system requires it. The keys in these oracle tables, including the Objid are usually Varchar2. I do not want to create a new column in 20+ tables if it can be prevented so i was wondering if ORA_HASH would do the trick.

My question is:
If i run e.g.

```
Select  ora_hash(order_no || release_no || line_no)  from purchase_order_line
```

with changing data in the table, will i always get the same hash value for a certain order_no || release_no || line_no combination? Or will that hash value be different at different times and if the overall data in the table changes. If the hash value remains constant i can limit it to the max size of the bigint required by the 3rd party system and always get the same unique value for a certain combination, right? Any issues with my line of thinking?
What would happen if we ever switch to a new Database, migrating all our data. I strongly assume we would get different datasets per combiantion then before, right?

The amount of lines in the table will not exceed the max value of a BIGINT.

I tried the query multiple times while adding and deleting data from the table and it always returned the same hash.

```
Select  ora_hash(order_no || release_no || line_no)  from purchase_order_line
```

I also did a quick check on a few tables with more data and we seem to have no collisions on the primary keys.

Comment: Constant, yes. Unique, probably.

Comment: `ora_hash('ABC' || 'DEF' || 'GHI')` will be the same as `ora_hash('A' || 'BCD' || 'EFGHI')`. This seems like a bad way to implement a hash.

Comment: Any specific reason you want to hash ? The function sys_guid generates large and unique values. In our projects they're used as generated primary keys. If there is every a migration/merge of multiple datasets, risks of collisions are minimal. But this does require data model changes of course.  On the other hand, 20+ tables doesn't seem like a lot.

Comment: Yeah i looked into it a bit more and chances of ora_hash producing duplicates is significant. The reason we are not using Sys_guid is because the return is alphanumeric, while we need a numeric value only. I am not sure it's possible at all without an extra column we fill with a sequence. In the given Example the string would have up to 20 chars (alpha and numeric, Upper an lowercase). Mathematical you cannot fit the amount of possible combinations into a BIGINT or am i missing something?

Comment: You can convert guids to decimal with `to_number ( sys_guid(), 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' )`

Comment: @ChrisSaxon: yeah, but that would not work with BIGINT. Decimals would have ~38 decimals and i need to convert that to Integer...

Comment: There is no `bigint` type in Oracle Database. `number` can have up to 38 digits of precision, so these values will fit.

Comment: @ChrisSaxon: Yeah but the id is needed for the 3rd party system. From their specification they seem to be using a MSQL Database where BIGINT datatype is limited from -9223372036854775807 to 9223372036854775807

Comment: @MT0: yeah that would be easy to solve by e.g. ora_hash('ABC' || '-' || 'DEF' ||  '-' || 'GHI'), but turns out it's not the only issue... Doesn't look like i'll get around adding additional columns

Comment: You can do better than `ORA_HASH` which has a high collision rate. Consider instead `dbms_crypto.hash` or `STANDARD_HASH`. You can get much more uniqueness from these to avoid collisions, even at the weaker `SHA1` algorithm. You can go with much higher bit algorithms too. And yes, the return values are deterministic so they will always be the same given the same input.

Comment: @PaulW: Yes, but these are alpha numeric in return while we need a numeric value. Every row in the ERP alrady has a unique objid which is alphanumeric. Unfortunatly the target system needs a unique numeric ID. Don't ask me who came up with designing it that way, imo it's a very poor choice.

Comment: They aren't alphanumeric, they are raw (visibly represented as hexadecimal). While you could convert them to a number, you'll run out of the 128 bit limitation of Oracle numbers quickly. The numeric datatype is your primary limitation, not the hashing functions available to you. And I do agree with others than there is a design issue here. Hashing is useful for identifying unique large text values, not as a substitute for normal primary keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are required to add a unique numeric ID to your tables, and you want to avoid this, because your tables already have a unique ID albeit alphanumeric. You are looking for a way to get to a deterministic numeric ID.

Depending on how many different characters are allowed in these IDs and how long these IDs can become, the following PL/SQL function may be sufficient to get from your alphanumeric ID to a numeric ID. (Too many allowed characters or too long alphanumeric IDs would cause an overflow exception.)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_unique_id(p_objid VARCHAR2) RETURN INTEGER DETERMINISTIC
IS
  PRAGMA UDF;
  v_allowed  VARCHAR2(4000) := 'ABCDEDGIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
  v_factor   INTEGER     := 1;
  v_result   INTEGER     := 0;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. LENGTHC(p_objid) LOOP
    v_result := v_result + INSTRC(v_allowed, SUBSTRC(p_objid, i, 1)) * v_factor;
    v_factor := v_factor * (LENGTHC(v_allowed) + 1);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN v_result;
END get_unique_id;
```

It is rather simple after all. You have a string of allowed characters that you use to get from your objid characters to a number.

Let's say there are 99 allowed characters. The first character in your objid will get a value from 1 to 99 depending on its position in the allowed characters string. The next character will get a value from 1 to 99 multiplied with 100. And so on. The sum of all these values is the resulting numeric ID. (You can of course run through your objid string from right to left instead, if you find this more intuitive.)

How to test the function:

```
select get_unique_id('0000000000') from dual;
```

Change '0000000000' to a string of the maximal allowed number of characters in your objid and the last allowed character in v_allowed. Do you get a result or an exception? Is the resulting number too big are small enough to match the requirement?

---

At last, a look on the docs for `ORA_HASH` ([docs.oracle.com/../ORA_HASH.html](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ORA_HASH.html#GUID-0349AFF5-0268-43CE-8118-4F96D752FDE6)):

```
ORA_HASH(expr [,max_bucket])
```

> There are no restrictions on the length of data represented by expr

> The optional max_bucket argument determines the maximum bucket value returned by the hash function. You can specify any value between 0 and 4294967295. The default is 4294967295.

This means there is an unlimited number of input values and a limited number of resulting hash values. In other words, different input can result in the same output. So, you cannot use this function for your purpose. The same is true for about every generic hash function you can find. Only if a hash function is written to generate a unique result for a known, limited set of input data, would it work for you. And well, in that context you can call my function above a non-generic hash function.

And a remark on deterministic functions: Oracle knows deterministic functions that are explicitly declared deterministic, just as I declared mine. These functions are guaranteed to return deterministic results, i.e. always the same output value for the same input value. So, if `ORA_HASH` is deterministic, this means that when you use it in your Oracle version, it will reliably result in the same output whenever you call it with the same input. It doesn't matter whether your Oracle version is 12c or 19c or 21c or whatever. It is not guaranteed, however, that Oracle never changes the algorithm. So while the function may be deterministic in Oracle 12c and still be deterministic in 21c, it is not guaranteed that the two versions will produce the same results. So, unless Oracle explicitly says so, the function is not guaranteed to be deterministic *across* database versions.

Comment: Thanks for the long answer. The allowed string here would be 'ABCDEDGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890/+'.

Comment: I will look at the table keys individually and maybe find some case specific logic that would work. If not, extra columns in the table is the last resort. Sill, thanks for the extensive answer

Comment: Old disappeard comment: Really interesting and i will keep this one for future uses :-). Running a quick test the output on a (up to) 20 characters Objid is 79301557162312826337222065954791. As i said before, mathematical it's impossible to create a generic hash function that returns a unique numerical id that would fit into a BIGINT as obviously the possible amount of combinations is a lot bigger (with a 20 char string). I have given up on the idea of using a hash function/ a custom hash function. Nothing else comes to mind either as i cannot use e.g. Rownum due to obvious reasons.

Answer (score 0):

ora_hash may lead to some collisions. Better would be to use standard_hash. That  returns raw, but is less likely to have collisions. And, if you hash a concatenation of columns, better do something like standard_hash(order_no ||'|'||release_no ||'|'|| line_no, 'MD5'). Use concatenation with | so as to avoid confusions such as 'ab'||'c' gives the same result as 'a'||'bc'.